# How do I troubleshoot this error in the new AWS SDK?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am trying to upload files to AWS S3 from a Node application. It is throwing me an error on load.

The relevant part of the package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.332.0",
    "@aws-sdk/lib-storage": "^3.332.0",
```

My initial load:

```
const { Upload } = require('@aws-sdk/lib-storage');
const { S3Client } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
const stream = 'node:stream';
const client = new S3Client({});
```

The relevant code:

```
function fileWriteStreamHandler(file) {
    const body = new stream.PassThrough();
    const upload = new Upload({
        client,
        params: {
            Key: `files/${Date.now().toString()}-${file.originalFilename}`,
            ContentType: file.mimetype,
            ACL: 'public-read',
            Bucket: s3Config.bucket,
            Body: body,
        },
    });
    const uploadRequest = upload.done().then((response) => {
        file.location = response.Location;
    });
    s3Uploads.push(uploadRequest);
    return body;
}
```

The error:

```
An error has occured. error is: C:\...\node_modules\@aws-sdk\client-s3\dist-cjs\runtimeConfig.js:32
        runtime: "node",
        ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'runtime'
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1293:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1096:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:935:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:112:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\...\node_modules\@aws-sdk\client-s3\dist-cjs\S3Client.js:18:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1239:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1293:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1096:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:935:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:112:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:...\node_modules\@aws-sdk\client-s3\dist-cjs\S3.js:98:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1239:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1293:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1096:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:935:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:112:18) and stack trace is: C:\...\node_modules\@aws-sdk\client-s3\dist-cjs\runtimeConfig.js:32
        runtime: "node",
        ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'runtime'
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1293:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1096:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:935:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:112:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\...\node_modules\@aws-sdk\client-s3\dist-cjs\S3Client.js:18:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1239:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1293:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1096:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:935:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:112:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\...\node_modules\@aws-sdk\client-s3\dist-cjs\S3.js:98:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1239:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1293:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1096:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:935:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:112:18) Process will restart now.
```

Comment: Are you using node version >= 14?

Comment: I am, Node 19.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Deleting node modules and package-lock.json, then rerunning npm i fixed this.